# Good aproach to create binary columns in relational database?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm building a master table which must contain some binary columns depending on some data from another tables. Let me show an example:
Master table is like: date | column_a | column_b | column_c | binarycolumn_a |...

The other table is like: date | column_z.

So the main goal here is to fill binarycolumn_a with 1 if a date from master table is in  the other table and 0 otherwise.

I've written a code with pandas library consisting in comparing dates from master table and the other table, but master table is so big that it takes forever to end. I'm looking for a good approach to face this problem as I'm totally lost.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `df1['binarycolumn_a']=df1['date'].isin(df2['date]).astype(int)` , something like this

Comment: I'm gonna try this as it looks like a very good approach! What would it look like if i had to compare two columns? date with date and column_z with column_a for example?

Comment: if you want to look that the value of column_a is in column_z like date with date, you can use like @anky_91 with `&` like `df1['binarycolumn_a']=(df1['date'].isin(df2['date']) & df1['col_a'].isin(df2['col_z'])).astype(int)`

Comment: Thank you two very much, you saved my day :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As anky_91 and ALFAFA correctly indicated, the answer for a column comparison is:

```
df1['binarycolumn_a']=df1['date'].isin(df2['date]).astype(int)
```

For two (or more) is:

```
df1['binarycolumn_a']=(df1['date'].isin(df2['date']) & 
df1['col_a'].isin(df2['col_z'])).astype(int)
```